# How to change the date format in datatables columfilter plugin(date filter)?

Tags: jquery

I am using datatables column filter plugin:

```
It has default date filter as this format:-24/07/2012
But I have to filter the data in this format:-24-07-2012..??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your [own renderer](http://datatables.net/usage/columns#fnRender):

In `aoColumns` in the date columns add a custom render callback, e.g. (untested):

```
fnRender: function (oObj) {
    var oDate = new Date(oObj.aData[0]);
    return '<div class="date">' + oDate.getDate() + '-' + oDate.getMonth() + '-' + oDate.getFullYear() + '<div>';
}
```

Also see [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html).